# Is variable_conflict use_variable not working with ON CONFLICT clause of UPSERT?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am frequently using variable_conflict use_variable, and so far I've never had any problems with it. However, it does not work with `ON CONFLICT` clause of `UPSERT`. Here is my repro:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id serial not null,
  CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARY KEY(id),
  category_id INT NOT NULL,
  tname TEXT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT test_unq UNIQUE(category_id, tname),
  some_info TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_test(category_id INT, tname TEXT, some_info TEXT)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
#variable_conflict use_variable
DECLARE
  resultId INTEGER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test(category_id, tname, some_info)
      SELECT category_id, tname, some_info
      ON CONFLICT(category_id, tname) DO NOTHING;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE 
  COST 100;

SELECT insert_test(1, 'Colors', 'Blue');

ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO test(category_id, tname, some_info)
      SELECT category_id, tname, some_info
      ON CONFLICT(category_id, tname) DO NOTHING"
```

Without #variable_conflict use_variable everything works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_test2(p_category_id INT, p_tname TEXT, p_some_info TEXT)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  resultId INTEGER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test(category_id, tname, some_info)
      SELECT p_category_id, p_tname, p_some_info
      ON CONFLICT(category_id, tname) DO NOTHING;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE 
  COST 100; 

SELECT insert_test2(1, 'Colors', 'Blue');
SELECT insert_test2(2, 'Colors', 'Red');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should post that to the Postgres (bugs-) mailing list. But in general it's not recommended to use parameters that have the same name as columns anyway, so I fail to see the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON CONFLICT` clause relies on index definitions, and the indexes can use arbitrary expressions (not necessarily referring to the table columns) in their definitions.

You can do this in PostgreSQL 9.5.2:

```
test=# CREATE TABLE test (id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, value INT);
CREATE TABLE

test=# CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_test ON test (value, (1));
CREATE INDEX

test=# INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (1);
INSERT 0 1

test=# INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (1);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ix_test"
ПОДРОБНОСТИ:  Key (value, (1))=(1, 1) already exists.

test=# INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (1) ON CONFLICT (value, (1)) DO NOTHING;
INSERT 0 0

test=# INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (1) ON CONFLICT (value, (2)) DO NOTHING;
ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

test=# INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (1) ON CONFLICT (value, (id)) DO NOTHING;
ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

test=# INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (1) ON CONFLICT (value, (no_such_column)) DO NOTHING;
ERROR:  column "no_such_column" does not exist
СТРОКА 1: ...INTO test (value) VALUES (1) ON CONFLICT (value, (no_such_co...

test=# INSERT INTO test (value) SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1)) q (n) ON CONFLICT (value, (n)) DO NOTHING;
ERROR:  column "n" does not exist
СТРОКА 1: ...CT * FROM (VALUES (1)) q (n) ON CONFLICT (value, (n)) DO NOT...
ПОДСКАЗКА:  There is a column named "n" in table "*SELECT*", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

test=# DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_test(INT); CREATE FUNCTION fn_test(n INT) RETURNS VOID AS $$ INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (1) ON CONFLICT (value, (n)) DO NOTHING; $$ LANGUAGE 'sql';
DROP FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION

test=# SELECT * FROM fn_test(1);
ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
КОНТЕКСТ:  SQL function "fn_test" during startup
```

For some reason, when doing unique index inference, PostgreSQL allows variables in index expressions.

It's probably a bug, because I can't think of any reason that would be justified.

Comment: Your write up is most useful. I concur: the feature makes little sense, might be a bug. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @AlexC: I've posted it to pgsql-bugs